# Inconsistent linkage between objects

Tags: object, module, attributes, ibm-doors

This is the code in *DXL*

```
string path = "blablabla...";
Module mod = read(path, false);

Object obj = object(1337, mod);

string nameObject;
Object objectObject;
Link lnk_in;
Link lnk_out;

print "The objects for IN links:\n";
for lnk_in in obj <- "*" do
{
    nameObject = source(lnk_in);
    objectObject = source(lnk_in);
    print identifier(objectObject) " " ;
    print nameObject "_" objectObject."Absolute Number" "\n";
}

print "\nThe objects for OUT links:\n";
for lnk_out in obj -> "*" do
{
    nameObject = target(lnk_out);
    objectObject = target(lnk_out);
    print identifier(objectObject) " ";
    print nameObject "_" objectObject."Absolute Number" "\n";
}
```

Basically it is interested in printing the objects linked with our **obj** object that has the given absolute number equal to 1337. I have chosen carefully this object, so that it would have both inner and outer links to other objects. However, despite it's simplicity, I have some problems.

On it's own, the script outputs:

```
The objects for IN links:

The objects for OUT links:
-R-E- DXL: <Line:25> null Object parameter was passed into argument position 1
-I- DXL: execution halted
```

As you may observe, there is a serious problem. The script doesn't return the inner objects, despite the fact that the **obj**, does have linked inner objects. Whereas, for the output links, I have observed that **nameObject** does return the string name of the object, but **objectObject** is a null.

If the second **for** is changed to:

```
print "\nThe objects for OUT links:\n";
for lnk_out in obj -> "*" do
{
    nameObject = target(lnk_out);
    objectObject = target(lnk_out);
    //print identifier(objectObject) " ";
    print nameObject "\n";
    print nameObject "_" objectObject."Absolute Number" "\n";
}
```

the output becomes:

```
The objects for OUT links:
etc...System_Req...etc
-R-E- DXL: <Line:27> null Object parameter was passed into argument position 1
-I- DXL: execution halted
```

What would be the problem? It isn't supposed to be like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is that in order to get access to an object, you need to open the module containing this object.

When you loop through out links you only have access to the attributes of the link itself, e.g. target (of type object), module (of type module).
So, you need to open the target module before having access to the target object.

For inlinks it is even a bit more complicated, as a module only stores out links. In links are not stored in a module. Instead you have LinkRefs, which you can also use to open the source module, then you have access to the links and the source objects.

I suggest to create two DXL layout columns using the link analysis wizard, one for incoming links, one for outgoing links. The code that is generated from the wizard shows you how to access these attributes.

Keep in mind that following links to baselines is even one step more complicated, as you have to open (“load”) the correct baseline (see “versioned links” in the DXL manual)

There are also numerous posts about links in the Rational DXL forum at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000001527, search for terms like LinkRef, showOut, showIn

Comment: From what I've tested, it seems that using the analysis wizard, it indeed helped me output the correct values.